# Setting 2 static directories in express node

Tags: node.js, express, angular2-routing

I have set up 2 static directories in express node as below.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/admin_public'));    
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client_public'));
```

My doubt is whether I can connect the express server to angular 2 like below:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_public/index.html'));
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client_public/index.html'));
});
```

If the above 2 `res.sendFile()` are correct, when I build my hybrid app for angular.

1) How do I access my server (will it be something like: `localhost:8080/client/public` and `localhost:8080/admin_public`) for 2 different frontends, one for client and one for admin?

2) Is it the right way of connecting the express to 2 `index.html`'s? If not, how should it be?

Answer (score 1):

To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static function, specify a mount path for the static directory, as shown below:

```
app.use('/client', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public')));

app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin/public')));
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the `/client` or `/admin` path prefix.

```
localhost:8000/client/
localhost:8000/admin/
```

Comment: Ok let me try and revert